# react-responsive-carousel change next and back button

Tags: react-responsive-carousel

I am using the react-responsive-carousel library. Here, I want to change the default previous and next button. And render navigation buttons always visible
My code is

```
<Carousel 
                        showThumbs={true}
                        showStatus={false}
                        infiniteLoop
                        // emulateTouch
                        // autoPlay
                        useKeyboardArrows
                        // axis="vertical"
                        // selectedItem={1}
                        width="1000px"
                    >
                        <div>
                            <Card1 />            
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Card2 />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                             <Card3 />
                        </div>
                    </Carousel>
```

I want to go from this (figure 1 ) to this (figure 2)[image: figure1]

[image: figure 2]

Comment: Hopefully some day you get an answer because their documentation is pretty bad and outdated. i just started using it a couple of days ago and only managed to change the slide indicators.